# Notifications in android app

Tags: android-layout, android-intent, android-activity

I am confused,how to implement an android app where the notifications are to be displayed inside the activity(For Example notifications button in facebook mobile app).

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to have some sort of list containing notifications, with a "read" key that is either true or false. based on this list you can display an icon with a number of unread notifications. You can check this at regular intervals or only at startup, however you want.

Have a look at this if you want to make use of android notifications:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html